# ASP.NET Identity Add / Import External User Automatically

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have an app that uses Microsoft ASP.NET Core Identity. A user that wishes to use Azure AD as an external login provider must first login with their (Core Identity) User Id and password, and link their Azure AD account using the ExternalLogins page (part of the Profile in ASP.NET Core Identity). This results in a row appearing in the dbo.AspNetUserTokens table, with a AuthenticatorKey stored against the userid.

Is there any way of importing this information from Azure AD without each individual user having to go through the first step of associating their account? For an organisation with dozens or hundreds of users an automatic import would be a better option if this was possible.

Comment: Can you [get a list of users in your tenant using Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0)?

Comment: Hi I would imagine so. I haven't tried.

Comment: So if you are able to get the list of the users from Azure AD, should be possible then to link them to your Identity users. Right?

Comment: If you will can be done as part of the user login process OR anytime you click a button OR ...

Comment: The graph api doesn't appear to return the information I Need, AspNetUserTokens contains UserId (this is internal to ASP.NET Core Identity), LoginProvider "[AspNetUserStore]" Name "AuthenticatoryKey" and Value - its the value that is encrypted and I don't think is available. Lets face it if I could get it it means I can log into the app using their identity... So this is most likely not going to be possible. I don't I just want to register them for the app. Its a shame ASP.NET Core Identity doesn't have this feature.

Comment: I feel you... short term fix can be to create a documentation page with screenshots (or even a video) explaining the process for such users

Comment: I already have a wizard that just allows the user to login and if they haven't assigned their MS account, it goes to the profile page to assign their MS user. This might well be the best we can do.